# Rails - set field of self to value of field of associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Probably it is so easy that I can't imagine :-) yet these examples throw errors

I am trying to set the value of an attribute of an instance to equal the value of an attribute of an associated record.

**Case 1** - for the Annotation model the Business Partner has a belongs_to relationship (`sender_id`) and I want to assign the value of the field `language` of the business partner to the field `locale_language` of the Annotation where the business_partner_id equals to the sender_id of the Annotation and I tried this:

```
def set_field_values
  self.locale_language = BusinessPartner.language.where(business_partner_id => self.sender_id) unless self.locale_language.present?
end
```

and for **case 2** 3 models are involved: Document, Documentttype and Annotation. I want to assign the value of the `documenttype_id` of `Annotation` to the `documenttype_id` field of the `Document`. Annotation has scope active.

```
unless self.documenttype.present?
  self.documenttype_id = Annotation.documenttype_id.active.where(annotation.sender_id => self.sender_id)
end
```

How is it done?

### Updated

for case 1, the error is NoMethodError.

> NoMethodError in AnnotationsController#create
>   undefined method `language' for #

for case 2

> NoMethodError in DocumentsController#create undefined method
>   `documenttype_id' for #

Comment: Might be worth showing your errors but in the first case shouldn't it be using a symbol - BusinessPartner.language.where(business_partner_id: self.sender_id) - and what is language - is that a class level method on BusinessPartner?

Comment: tried it - returns error as per update

Comment: aye but you seem to have more than one error - it looks like you are attempting to access an instance attribute at class level - I assume that you have an association between BusinessPartner and Language models ... yet you have BusinessPartner.language

Comment: For now language is attribute on businesspartner model. `self.sender_id` refers to `BusinessPartner` from where I want to pick the language to set as value for `self.locale.language` (case 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I was able to achieve it using an approach where first I look up the associated record, then use `.select` or .take to get the field or record. For example like so:

```
self.documenttype ||= Documenttype.active.default.take
```

Assuming default is true only for 1 record - achievable with:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :default, if: :default?, message: "Another document type is set as default"
```

it can work like so...

```
self.language = BusinessPartner.where(:business_partner_id => self.sender_id).select("language") unless self.language.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the first error try:

```
self.locale_language = Language.where(business_partner_id: self.sender_id) unless self.locale_language.present?
```

Assuming business_partner_id is associated with Language model

Comment: nope it is not (yet :-) ) language is attribute on businesspartner

Comment: you need to include more information then. can you add the models to your question otherwise people are just trying to second guess what you have :). Either way you cannot do BusinessPartner.language - language is an attribute of a model instance - not an attribute of the model class.